# how to set unified plan in semantics webrtc android

Tags: webrtc, webrtc-android

how to set a unified plan in semantics Webrtc android.
 I need to add it to SDP. I have tried below code but it's not working

```
       rtcConfig.sdpSemantics = PeerConnection.SdpSemantics.UNIFIED_PLAN
```

Comment: How do I set up multiple different audio soruces after setting up UNIFIED_PLAN?

Answer (score 2):

I do something like this and it works. Give it a try:

```
rtcConfiguration = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers);
rtcConfiguration.iceTransportsType = PeerConnection.IceTransportsType.ALL;
rtcConfiguration.iceCandidatePoolSize = 2;
rtcConfiguration.bundlePolicy = PeerConnection.BundlePolicy.MAXCOMPAT;
rtcConfiguration.sdpSemantics = PeerConnection.SdpSemantics.UNIFIED_PLAN;
rtcConfiguration.continualGatheringPolicy = PeerConnection.ContinualGatheringPolicy.GATHER_CONTINUALLY;
rtcConfiguration.candidateNetworkPolicy = PeerConnection.CandidateNetworkPolicy.ALL;
```

Comment: How do I set up multiple different audio soruces after setting up UNIFIED_PLAN?

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, you can do the following:

```
val peerConnection = peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(
        RTCConfiguration(iceServers).apply {
            sdpSemantics = SdpSemantics.UNIFIED_PLAN
        },
        constraints,
        observer
    )
```

Comment: How do I set up multiple different audio soruces after setting up UNIFIED_PLAN?